# Jenkins failed but cmd run wihout error

Tags: jenkins, rake

Getting dif result when run script below from Jenkins:

```
C:/Ruby21-x64/bin/ruby.exe -I'C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-support-3.4.1/lib';'C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.4.1/lib' 'C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.4.1/exe/rspec' --pattern 'spec/**/*_spec.rb'
.

Finished in 0.001 seconds (files took 0.87208 seconds to load)
1 example, 0 failures
```

See no error code and dont know what's happened:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Rake_test>exit 0 
[RubymineProjects] $ C:\Ruby21-x64\bin\rake.bat --rakefile C:\Users\user\RubymineProjects\Rake_test\Rakefile.rb
C:\Ruby21-x64\bin -I'C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-support-3.4.1/lib';'C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.4.1/lib' 'C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.4.1/exe/rspec' --pattern 'spec/**/*_spec.rb' failed
C:\Ruby21-x64\bin -I'C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-support-3.4.1/lib';'C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.4.1/lib' 'C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.4.1/exe/rspec' --pattern 'spec/**/*_spec.rb'
Build step 'Invoke Rake' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What happens if you ssh into the Jenkins build machine as the Jenkins user and run the command from the command line there?

Comment: Jenkins installed at the same machine. It's windows. Jenkins service run from system account.

Comment: Is the environment of the system account identical to your user account?

Comment: only one user available, and it has admin root. local variables and system has path to ruby/bin

Comment: run service from user and get the same resut

Comment: Could you try and run the *rake.bat* file from the CMD and then run: `echo Exit Code is %errorlevel%`. What us the result?

Comment: C:\Ruby21-x64\bin>rake.bat echo Exit Code is %errorlevel%
rake aborted!
No Rakefile found (looking for: rakefile, Rakefile, rakefile.rb, Rakefile.rb)
(See full trace by running task with --trace)

C:\Ruby21-x64\bin>echo Exit Code is %errorlevel%
Exit Code is 1

Comment: Find the solution by remove "name" and "RUBY_HOME" fields at Jenkins -> Settings -> Rake.